# Syntax error I don't understand

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

**edit:** cleaned this question up by removing unneccessary detail

I'm trying to use data mapper with ruby, but I keep getting this syntax error, and I have no idea how to fix it:

```
user.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting $end
include DataMapper...
                        ^
```

user.rb:

```
require 'data_mapper'

class User 
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,           Serial  #serial means auto-incrementing PK
    property :uname,        String, :key=>true
    property :name,         String
    property :email,        String
    property :is_locked,    Boolean, :default=>false
    property :image,        String
    property :must_change_psw, String, :default=>false

    property :salt,         String, :accessor=>:private
    property :hash,         String, :accessor=>:private

    #returns true if the password provided is correct AND the user is not locked
    def correct? (pass)
        return (self.hash==hash(pass,self.salt))&!self.is_locked
    end

end

def hash(secret,salt)
    return true #for now
end
```

Comment: I'll download and install a previous version to try

Comment: tried this with ruby 1.9.1, same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this file was saved in a Mac format - new lines were encoded as `\r` instead of \n.

Ruby doesn't seem to like that.

To fix it I used `tr '\r' '\n' < user.rb > user.rb`